# How to better debug a WebService asmx -- 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, web-services, json

I need the errors from my web service sent directly to the client in Json format so I can read exactly what error is being thrown. How do I do this please?

This is what I keep getting in Fiddler

```
Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Server code

```
  <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
 Protected Function PopulateUsers() As IDictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim users As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Try
            Dim arry As ArrayList =  UserController.GetUsers(0, True)
            For Each objUser As Users In arry 
                userrole.Add(CStr(objUser.UserID), objUser)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim ur As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Dim s As New User
            s.DisplayName = ex.GetBaseException.StackTrace
            s.UserID = 1
            users.Add(ex.GetBaseException.Message, s)
            Return s
        End Try

        Return users 
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have proper error handling in your web service. In case of any error, convert your error object into a well formed json object and send it. In the client side, success handler will only be invoked but you need to check whether the response contains the error object or the actual response and act accordingly.

There is error in your catch block, try this

```
Protected Function PopulateUsers() As IDictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim users As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Try
            Dim arry As ArrayList =  UserController.GetUsers(0, True)
            For Each objUser As Users In arry 
                userrole.Add(CStr(objUser.UserID), objUser)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim ur As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

            ur.Add("ERROR", ex.GetBaseException.StackTrace)
            Return ur
        End Try

        Return users 
    End Function
```

Comment: How do I do that, and make sure is transmitted to the client

Comment: it is in .NET. I need to know how to get the error message thrown to the client. I have laced my code in Try-catches and even tried serializing and setting the Custom Error mode to REMOTEONLY, but none of that has worked so far.

Comment: What is the return type of this webmethod?

Comment: In the exception block, you can create a new Dictionary object, serialize the exception object into string and set this as a value of the new Dictionary object with some key as `ERROR`. In the client side success handler look for this `ERROR` key and decide accordingly.

Comment: I tried that approach as well but that does not seem to work. I keep getting the same error screen but not the actual error itself. I even set in the client a pop up to display the error but still nothing but a generic message

Comment: I just posted the code. I am able to test locally that this works but once I move the same code to remote dev environment, I am unable to get it working.

Comment: Can you comment out the line to set the DisplayName with StackTrace and try? I mean don't send the StrackTrace info and try.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be with those lines either

Comment: There is a error in your catch block also because of which you are getting unhandled exception

Answer (score 0):

Use [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to get a full set of error logging with reports and alerts.